# Initializing an array with NULL pointer with GCC throw error

Tags: c, gcc, iar

I am using GCC and IAR to compile some C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

uint8_t tab[] = NULL;
```

this exmple code throw this error with GCC :  error: invalid initializer

With IAR compiler the syntax is accepted

What is wrong here with GCC and why it is accepted by IAR compiler?

Comment: How many elements are in your array?

Comment: Apart from the fact that `NULL` is a pointer value, the syntax is incorrect. `uint8_t tab[] = { 0, 1, 2 };` will generate an array with three elements.

Comment: The idea is to have an array with zero element, I mean this is only a part of the generic code where the array can take 0 to n element but in same cases the array must be with size 0.
The syntax is accepted with iar and armcc compiler , I got the problem only with gcc

Comment: I'd say the question is backwards, it's more interesting why other compilers even allow this.

Comment: `The idea is to have an array with zero element,` that's not possible. An array has to have positive size. `The syntax is accepted with iar and armcc compiler` it's a compiler extension (or just undefined behavior) and my guess is the array has 1 element anyway.

Comment: What you posted does not compile with MSVC. The lack of `{` braces `}` is an error, after correcting that the `NULL` generates a warning. *'initializing': 'uint8_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'*

Comment: @WeatherVane actually what you did is you initialized tab first element with NULL but this is not what I wanted to do, I wanted to have the array pointing to NULL.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to an array like that. The closest you can get is `uint8_t *tab = NULL;` but that is not an array with zero elements. It is a pointer with a `NULL` value.

Comment: I have a solution for this which is uint8_t tab[] ={}; this will work for gcc but my problem is that I need to have this code compiling for both iar and gcc and iar doesn't accept this syntax

Comment: In that case you should show the actual syntax you used in the question. This is looking like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is more likely that this is the last member of a `struct` which you will dynamically allocate. As posted the array is useless. In this revised case MSVC will compile `uint8_t tab[];` but it will not compile `uint8_t tab[] ={};` What is the point in trying to initialise an array with no elements?

Comment: I will give overview of this code, the idea is to have a generic multi dimentional array that include other arrays. this multi-dim array is having inside macros and each macro when expanded will be replaced by already defined array.
now those arrays can be with any size depending from the use case because those will be testvector to be used with crypto accelator IP and I have the case where an input must be array with 0 element

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside the header files than you can notice that NULL is actually

```
#define NULL ((void*)0) // a void pointer type data.
```

whereas, when you declare an array with following syntax

```
uint8_t tab[] // This is not basically a pointer | it is an array.
```

you are assigning a pointer data type to an array datatype that is the issue.

Comment: IAR and armcc compiler does accept this syntax and ddin't get error with it.
The error appears only with gcc.
So I am wondering what is the difference here

Comment: Each compiler is implemented by different organizations and targets different operating systems and hardwares for example. the gcc, mingw and vc++ compilers target x86 architecture but they handle and represent errors in different ways that is the only difference.

but the basic concept of why this expression is not working is on the above answer

Comment: legacy compilers used the `[]` notation (with nothing between the two brackets, to declare a pointer (and this notation persists in the parameter declaration)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array with any positive number of element, but you can not assign the array with `NULL` or `int`. But you can compare the array with `NULL` pointer.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t tab[] = {}; // it's OK but it does not make sense with 0 element in the array
// uint8_t tab[] = {0}; it's OK size of array  = 1
// uint8_t tab[] = {0,1,2,3}; // it is OK, size of array = 2
int main() {

    if(tab == NULL) { // it's OK, you can compare
        // do sth
    }
    // tab = NULL it's not accepted
    // tab = 0x1010101 it's not accepted also

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(tab)); // it will print 0
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use dynamically array with `size = 0`:

```
uint8_t *tab2;
...
tab2 = malloc(0);
// do something
tab2 = realloc(tab2, 3); // re-allocate the pointer for lager size
```

Comment: this will be accepted by gcc uint8_t tab[] = {}; but not with iar, the code I will need to compile it for both iar and gcc so this is my nightmare here

Comment: You asked the question about GCC not IAR. But if you still want `size = 0`, you can use dynamically allocation.  Try: `uint8_t *tab = malloc(0);` then it you want to resize you can use `tab = realloc(tab, another size);`

Comment: Oh man, you don't have to do `malloc(0)`, you just can assign `NULL` and then `realloc(NULL, new size)` (you'll get a valid pointer).